# Asus Zenbook UX305 video driver repeatedly crashes

Tags: windows-8, laptop, gpu, asus-laptop

Multiple times a day I get this error:
[image]
"Display driver has stopped responding and has recovered".  The screen goes black for a few seconds and all programs that rely on the GPU shut down (Google Maps in Chrome, Google Earth, etc..)

I returned my first UX305 and got a replacement, but the replacement does it too!

I am still using Windows 8 which was pre-installed, but intend to install Linux Mint if I keep this laptop.

A little research shows some others with the same issue: [1](http://www.techradar.com/reviews/pc-mac/laptops-portable-pcs/asus-zenbook-ux305-1264384/review/3) [2](http://liliputing.com/2015/04/asus-zenbook-ux305-review-an-affordable-ultrabook-with-premium-design.html) [3](http://forums.redflagdeals.com/microsoft-store-asus-zenbook-ux305-2015-13-3-core-m-8gb-256gb-ssd-fhd-699-a-1677959/27/) [4](https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=722072784568750&id=626404180802278) ...but little in the way of a solution.

The problem seems a little more frequent when the battery is low(?).  It seems a bit more frequent when room temperature us warm.

Personally, I can't accept losing video for a few seconds every hour or so and restarting all my gpu programs, and I can't believe there isn't a recall if this is a hardware problem.

Does anyone have a solution (besides hoping an update will come along)?  Has anyone installed a different OS and had the problem be resolved?

My graphics card is: "Intel(R) HD Graphics 5300" according to Device Manager.
I was using driver version 10.18.10.xxx and after a BIOS update (from 208 to 210) am now running 10.18.14.4170 and the problem persists.

Comment: Do you have the latest video drivers installed?

Comment: And did you update the chipset drivers? Well, are drivers up to date using manufacturer drivers (not Windows drivers)

Comment: Specifically, what exact version of video drivers and of chipset drivers are you using?

Comment: OK. At the time I posted, I was running video driver 10.18.10.something (most current according to Windows).  Now, after a BIOS update, I am running 10.18.14.4170 (from the ASUS website).  I will have to wait and see if the problem is resolved...

Comment: this is the latest driver from Intel: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/24964/Intel-Iris-Iris-Pro-and-HD-Graphics-Driver-for-Windows-7-8-8-1-64-bit

Comment: @magicandre1981  It is?  I get the error: "The driver being installed is not validated for this computer" when trying to install.

Comment: The problem persists even with the most recent drivers.

Comment: tis is a generic driver. try to install the driver via device manager. But do a full backup before if you run into issues.

Comment: Issue persists on Windows 10 with newest drivers.

Comment: The only reliable way I have found to prevent these crashes is to leave the laptop plugged in when using the GPU.  I had to buy a car adapter for using mapping software while travelling.  I wonder if this is an issue with low battery voltage??